# PHP: How to count the number of rows

Tags: php

so far i made this OOP class but it not returning any values, any help guys i realy need it

```
public function countRows($table ='tb_cliente')
{
    if($this->tableExists($table)){
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM ".$table;
    $query = @mysql_query($sql);  
    if($query){
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
       }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it returning bool value

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the value of `$count`.

Try `return $count;`

Comment: As I said in the other answer also already, this doesn't serve anybody! It's seems to be only a simple typo!

Comment: @Rizier123 But simple typo can also be the answer.

Comment: @Hudixt It would be the most useless and poor "answer" there can be

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch all data if the only goal is to count rows. You can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

This returns the number of values of the specified column.

Or you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

which returns number of rows from selected table.

Or you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

which returns the number of distinct values of the specified column.

The way you are preforming to count rows in table is kind of unnecessary overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function countRows($table ='tb_cliente')
{
    if($this->tableExists($table)){
    $sql ="SELECT * totalrows FROM ".$table;
    $query = @mysql_query($sql);  
    if($query){
        $count = mysql_num_rows(sql );
        return $count;  
    }
    else{
        return false;`enter code here`
       }

}
```

or you can use:

```
    public function countRows($table ='tb_cliente')
{
    if($this->tableExists($table)){
    $sql ="SELECT count(*) as counted totalrows FROM ".$table;
    $query = @mysql_query($sql);  
    if($query){
        $count = mysql_result($query,0,"counted");
        return $count;  
    }
    else{
        return false;
       }

}
```